# NoneType' object has no attribute 'system

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a requirement to start a service once the packages installed by calling command tabpy and I used below and I get error. The same command can be executed without any issues manually in jupyter notebook by taping `!tabpy` manually
.**As such is there any other way we can call such commands from python script**

**my python script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
# In[ ]:
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().system('tabpy')
```

**My Error Message**

```
File "Tabpy_startup.py", line 8, in <module>
get_ipython().system('tabpy')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'system'
```

Comment: for some reason `get_ipython()` is `None`.

Comment: any idea how to fix this please

Comment: `get_ipython()` only returns if there's an ipython session running. See [This github question](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12334)

Comment: @G.Anderson actually you r right. is there any other way to call commands that we run in jupyter notebook with "!" example !tabpy  in a python script please??

Comment: That github link has a few possible solutions to try, such as running the script as a `.ipy` file

Comment: @G.Anderson thank you. is this what I do
import IPython as ipy
from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
shell = TerminalInteractiveShell.instance() ipy.embed(tabpy). Please advise